# Ruby Watir: Captcha Incorrect while browse with watir over simple login

Tags: ruby, authentication, watir, captcha

G'day fellow coders,

today I tried to browse a webpage with watir. But it turns out that even a simple Loginpage will overextend my knowledge. So.. I hope you guys have an Idea.

That is the Code I have:

```
require 'watir'
require 'open-uri'


class WebDrive
 attr_reader :arg1

  def initialize(arg1)
    website = arg1
    setup(website)
  end

  def setup(website)
    Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.driver_path="./assets/chromedriver"
    @browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
    @browser.goto(website)
    @browser.cookies.load './assets/cookies'
  end

  def runpage
    print "Enter the Username or Email: "
    usrname = gets.chomp
    print "Enter the Password: "
    password = gets.chomp
    print "Enter the Captcha you See: "
    captcha = gets.chomp
    proceed(usrname, password, captcha)
  end

  def proceed (usrname, password, captcha)
    @browser.text_field(:name, "uid").set usrname
    @browser.text_field(:name, "pwd").set password
    @browser.text_field(:name, "img").set captcha
    @browser.button(:type,"submit").click
    sleep 2
    @browser.cookies.save './assets/cookies2'
  end
end

page = WebDrive.new("http://www.someteststuff.com")
page.runpage
```

What happens?

1. Watir opens the correct browser
2. Watir opens the correct URL.
3. Watir ask me for the login credentials
4. Watir fills in the username, password and captcha field.
5. Page returns: Captcha incorrect.

So... I mean, yes. Im just a human and I can make mistakes by reading a pretty poor captcha. But not that often. I tried it almost 50 times and the page still returns that the captcha is incorrect. Whats going wrong?

Here is the HTML for this login form:

```
<input name="rlm" value="RESTRICTED" type="hidden">
<input name="for" value="httpsomestuffphp" type="hidden">
    <div id="header">Sign in</div><div id="err"></div>
        <label>Username</label>
          <input name="uid" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" type="text"> 
        <label>Password</label>
          <input name="pwd" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" type="password"> 
        <label>Enter the code</label><img class="show_img" src="/img.cptcha">
          <input name="img" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" type="text">
          <input name="rmb" value="y"> 
      <input id="submit" value="Sign In" type="submit">
```

Comment: What's the error are you receiving?

Comment: There is no error. Everything seems to work fine. But the website respond: "Incorrect captcha code".. nothing more. And the login fails because of that. Running this code against Facebook and Twitter without captcha works as intendet. But only the testpage, with captcha dont works. Browsing this site manually, in a real browser wont fail. So its not the website.

Comment: How your program knows what captcha appears? Is it a static captcha? Every time remain the same?

Comment: No. I see the page. Watir opens the automated browser.
The program ask me what I am seeing.

Comment: What if you manually enter the captcha and entering username and password through program via debug mode?

Comment: reCAPTCHA is designed to prevent what you are trying to accomplish.  You'll likely have better luck working with your developers to tweak the test environment to bypass it.  YMMV.